# how to sort a file having rows of values separated by space?

Tags: shell-script, sort

I have a text file with rows of latitudes and longitudes like so:

```
17.7003 17.7003 17.7004 17.7004 17.7005 17.7005 17.7005 17.7006 17.7006 17.7006 17.7007 17.7007 17.7008 17.7008 17.7008 17.7009 17.7009 17.701 17.701 17.701 17.7011 17.7011 17.7011 17.7012 17.7012 17.7013 17.7013 17.7013 17.7014 17.7014 17.7015 17.7015 17.7015 17.7016 17.7016 17.7016 17.7017 17.7017 17.7018 17.7018 17.7018 17.7019 17.7019 17.702 17.702 17.702 17.7021 17.7021 17.7021 17.7022 17.7022 17.7023 17.7023 17.7023 17.7024 17.7024 17.7025 17.7025 17.7025 17.7026 17.7026 17.7026 17.7027 17.7027 17.7028 17.7028 17.7028 17.7029 17.7029 17.703 17.703 17.703 17.7031 17.7031 17.7031 17.7032 17.7032 17.7033 17.7033 17.7033 17.7034 17.7034 17.7035 17.7035 17.7035 17.7036 17.7036 17.7036 17.7037 17.7037 17.7038 17.7038 17.7038 17.7039 17.7039 17.704 17.704 17.704 17.7041 17.7041 17.7041 17.7042 17.7042 17.7043 17.7043 17.7043 17.7044 17.7044 17.7045 17.7045 17.7045 17.7046 17.7046 17.7046 17.7047 17.7047 17.7048 17.7048 17.7048 17.7049 17.7049 17.705 17.705 17.705 17.7051 17.7051 17.7051 17.7052 17.7052 17.7053 17.7053 17.7053 17.7054 17.7054 17.7055 17.7055 17.7055 17.7056 17.7056 17.7056 17.7057 17.7057 17.7058 17.7058 17.7058 17.7059 17.7059 17.706 17.706 17.706 17.7061 17.7061 17.7061 17.7062 17.7062 17.7063 17.7063 17.7063 17.7064 17.7064 17.7065 17.7065 17.7065 17.7066 17.7066 17.7066 17.7067 17.7067 17.7068 17.7068
```

This is one row. I want to separate each latitude and make a column of latitudes. Like this I have 100 rows.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Show your desired output. Do you want to _transpose_ the file so that rows become columns? You say "separate each latitude": what about duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title mentions sorting, but your question itself seems to ask how to put each value on a line by itself

```
xargs printf '%s\n' <file
```

This assumes that items are separated by whitespace

Comment: That also assume the items don't contain single quotes, doubles quotes not backslashes (and is valid text in the locale and lines are not more than 1024 byte large with some xargs implementation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr`:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file
17.7003
17.7003
17.7004
17.7004
17.7005
[...]
17.7068
17.7068
```

If you need to sort it, you can pipe to `sort`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort
```

Your example data are already sorted, so that won't make a difference in this case.

You can also do the same thing with other tools. For instance, if you can have more than one consecutive space, sed, perl and awk would work better (note that the `sed` command assumes GNU `sed` or another sed that knows about `\n`):

```
sed -E 's/ +/\n/g' file
perl -pe 's/ +/\n/g' file
awk 'gsub(/ +/,"\n")' file
```

Comment: tHANK YOU SO MUCH. tHE FIRST COMMAND WORKED PERFECTLY.

Comment: You're welcome, @MeenakshiSreejith. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.